# Qt - OpenCV - FaceRecognizer - Exited with code 255

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm using OpenCV with Qt and I am trying to use the LBPHFaceRecognizer class.

I used the OpenCV documentation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzuWM.jpg 
https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html

So I added this function to my program

```
void MainWindow::trainRecognizer(){

    cv::Ptr<cv::face::FaceRecognizer> recognizer = 
cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer::create();
    std::vector<cv::String> filename;
    cv::glob("validDataSet\\*.jpg", filename, false);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images;
    std::vector<int> IDs;

   /*for (size_t i = 0; i < filename.size(); i++){
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(filename[i]) << "\n";
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(filename[i]);
    QString imageName = QString::fromStdString(filename[i]).split("\\").at(1);
    QString id = imageName.split('.').at(1);
    images.push_back(image);
    IDs.push_back(id.toInt());
    }
    recognizer->train(images,IDs);
    recognizer->save("Recognizer\\sylvain.yml");*/
}
```

My program won't start and exit with code 255.
And the issue is with this line (if I comment this line, there is no issue)

```
cv::Ptr<cv::face::FaceRecognizer> recognizer = 
cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer::create();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cv::Ptr<cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer> recognizer = 
cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer::create()`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work too, same error :(